# MSA60 error log in OpenVMS 8.3?

Tags: storage, hp, hp-modular-smart-array, hp-storageworks, openvms

I have two MSA60 (with rx2660 server under OPENVMS - RAID6), suddenly after replacing 3 faulty SAS disks with new ones, 11 old disks in one of the tower showing amber alert (predictive failure). I checked the controller (p800) with MSA UTILITY, and it is working fine. Can it be the storage backplane? Is there any command to get MSA60 error host logs in OpenVMS?
If the storage is faulty , do we need to replace the offline disks as well?

Comment: Do you have support with the manufacturer?

Comment: Isn't this thing a decade old and end of life? (Also, Itanium, gross.)  Maybe it's time to leave dead platforms to their eternal rest and get something supportable.  In your position, I would be sorely tempted to make it fail so I could say "oh no, it broke!  I guess we'll just have to replace it with something that isn't horrible, damn."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @ewwhite No support from HPE and they seem clueless.

Comment: @HopelessN00b It is 8 years old. Do they have life span like this?

Comment: This is all very old equipment. The MSA was a 2007-era product. It's possible that you have a bad backplane.

Comment: I am very newbie in this subject, sorry. I am not sure how to check MSA60 backplane. Server log error does not report anything but HDD failure.I checked the SAS and MSA utility, both working fine. I do not know if I replace MSA60 with a new one I will need to buy new 11 SAS drives or not (once they are reported failed, is it possible they are OK?)